# How to apply a new transform animation while other one is running on the same element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, less

I have a basic fixed animation on an element that runs when the user click on "space" :

```css
&.pop {
        animation: pop 1s ease-in 20ms 1 normal both;
}


@keyframes pop {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform-origin: 30px;
    }
    20% {
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
        transform-origin: 30px;
    }
    40% {
        transform: rotate(-10deg) translate(-2px, -20px);
        transform-origin: 30px;
    }
    60% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0, -40px);
        transform-origin: 30px;
    }
    80% {
        transform: rotate(3deg) translate(2px, -20px);
        transform-origin: 30px;
    }
    100% {
        transform:translate(0,0);
        transform-origin: 30px;
    }
}
```

Now, i want to add different other transform animations onkeydown that will run simultaneously with the current animation, for example :

```css
&.spin {
        animation: spin 500ms ease-out 20ms 1 forwards;
    }

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
}
```

So my problam is that when i am adding the second "spin" class, it runs over my first "pop" animation.
what will be the way to add it instead of running over ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understood your question correctly:
**you can use multiple animations within the transform :** 
**just like this :**

```
transform: rotate(90deg) translate(150px, -230px);
```

---

or you can use another approach: 
**you can wrap your target element with two outer divs and assign an animation for every div..** 
**just like this**

```
<div class="apply_this_animation">
    <div class="apply_this_animation_also">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="#" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**and use this in you CSS just like this:**

```
<style>
.apply_this_animation {
    transform: rotate(90deg); 
}

.apply_this_animation_also {
    transform: translate(150px, -230px); 
}
</style>
```

[Read More](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-apply-multiple-transform-property-to-an-element-using-css/)